# How to deal with a constraint in Genetic Algorithm when none of the population members obeys it?

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithm

My goal is to apply GA to find optimum locations to place a number of circles (equal dia) in a 2D plane such that no two circles are closer than a certain distance. I account for the proximity constrain by setting the fitness function to -1 if the constraint is broken but the problem is none of the initial population randomly generated follows the proximity constraint thus making the fitness of all the members -1.

By googling, I found that if the plane is separated in to grids with the size of clearance I won't have this problem, but I'm afraid it will miss a lot of potential solution. Is there a method to incorporate the proximity constraint or should I go with the grid?

Comment: Why don't you alter your fitness function to just impose a penalty proportional to the number that overlap?  Presumably, the other part of the fitness function credits more circles in general.  That way better solutions will be distinguishable.  When you "cross" solutions, there is almost certainly going to be some overlaps, so ya might as well put in a proportional penalty w/ larger weight than is given to "good" circles.

Comment: I tried that but the population never comes out of the proximity constraint.

Comment: what does "never comes out" mean?  Are you saying that the code takes a long time to execute or something else?

Comment: I meant that it never produces a solution where all the circles are farther than the clearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just random, start with a random solution with constraints. Generate one circle, then find the feasible space for next circle, create second circle and continue until you generate entire generation.

Comment: It solved my problem, but how do we make sure that further evolution doesn't lead to a population of infeasible solutions? will the inherent mechanism of GA prevent that?